# SQL query for returning rows with only certain values in list but not others?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks something like this:

| id | colors | other column | other column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red, green, blue | ... | ... |
| 2 | red, blue | ... | ... |
| 3 | red | ... | ... |
| 4 | white, blue, purple | ... | ... |
| 5 | green, white, purple | ... | ... |

I need a SQL query that would return the rows where the values match *only* those in my filter list, without returning rows which have any other values in the colors column.

The query I'm working from is this:

```
select * from table where colors in ('red', 'blue');
```

The problem with this one is that it will return rows 1-4 in the result, since each row has either red or blue in its colors. Instead, I want to return only rows 2 and 3, which are the only rows which don't have any extra colors outside of my filter list.

There could be any number of colors in the column, so I don't have a good list to use as a `NOT` filter unfortunately. I need to be able to return the entire row from the DB, including all available columns.

Appreciate any help or suggestions.

TIA!

Comment: Storing delmited values in a relational database violates first-normal form, a database works with columns of atomic values. I would suggest normalising your data.

Comment: I am pretty sure your query will only return row 3.

Comment: If set of colors is closed (e.g. all the future possible color names are known in advance) try excluding unnecessary `where not colors in ('white', ...etc)`

Comment: Create a new, and better, data model. That's where your problem started, multiple values in a single column. Fix it as soon as possible, that will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks all, appreciate the feedback. I'll go back to the drawing board for DB design :) . Is there guidance if I do need to store a list of values? Is it better to store a JSON blob within the column rather than a pure list?

Comment: Store json only if you need to pull it out in its entirely. You need to learn about normalisation, plenty of good tutorials to be Googled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other pointed out in the comment section this is really a bad design and will cause more pain in the future, fix it if possible.

See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Regarding the question,

First split the comma separated string

```
SELECT 
  id,
  TRIM(UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(colors, ','))) AS colors
FROM my_table
```

Result

```
id  colors
1   red
1   green
1   blue
2   red
2   blue
3   red
......
```

Then filter the results

```
with cte as  (
        SELECT id,
               TRIM(UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(colors, ','))) AS colors
        FROM my_table
) select id
  from cte 
group by id
having count (distinct colors) = 2 
  and min(colors) = 'blue'
  and max(colors) = 'red';
```

Result

```
id
2
```

If you need all the columns use,

```
with split_string as  (
        SELECT id,
               TRIM(UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(colors, ','))) AS colors
        FROM my_table
), ids as (
             select id
             from split_string 
             group by id
             having count (distinct colors) = 2 
             and min(colors) = 'blue'
             and max(colors) = 'red'
  ) select m.*
    from my_table m 
    inner join ids i on i.id=m.id;
```

Result

```
id  colors
2   red, blue
```

See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sd7KYfnG)

Answer (score 0):

Upd1.
select rows, containing colors from list, and no other colors:

```
with ItemColors as(
select id,color,count(*)over(partition by id) color_cnt
from( select id,trim(unnest(string_to_array(colors,','))) color
     from test )x
)
,ColorCounts as(
select id,count(*),max(color_cnt) cnt
from ItemColors
where color in('blue','green','red')
group by id
having count(*)=max(color_cnt)
)
select t.*
from test t
inner join ColorCounts c on c.id=t.id
```

Result for this list of colors ('blue','green','red')

| id | colors | othercolumn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red,green, blue | ... ... |
| 2 | red,blue | ... ... |
| 3 | red | ... ... |

Old answer:

Rows, containing any of color from list ('blue','purple','yellow','black')

```
with ItemColors as(
select *
  ,trim(unnest(string_to_array(colors,','))) color
from test
)
select distinct id,colors,othercolumn
from ItemColors
where color in('blue','purple','yellow','black')
```

Result

| id | colors | othercolumn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red,green, blue | ... ... |
| 2 | red,blue | ... ... |
| 4 | white,blue, purple | ... ... |
| 5 | green, white, purple | ... ... |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7yaAdF6p)

Comment: The OP specifies  *I need a SQL query that would return the rows where the values match only those in my filter list, without returning rows which have any other values in the colors column.*

Comment: @ErgestBasha, your comment is about my answer?

Comment: Yes, the answer you provided it is not related to the OP requests , thus its wrong

Comment: @ErgestBasha, Thank you. I understood the question somewhat differently. I will complete my answer.